# how to send percent progress in laravel controller with for and flush()

Tags: php, laravel, flush

how can i do to return values ​​from inside the `for` one by one, to inside `ajax`. I'm trying to use `flush()` but I'm not getting the result I want, because it executes everything for later to bring me the values. and I need the values ​​to be printed one by one until the end of the `for`.
here is the `controller` part:

```
    public function store(Request $request){
        for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++){
            echo json_encode(['percent' => $i]);
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

here is the `ajax` part:

```
         $.ajax({
           
            url: "{{route('percent.do')}}",
            type: "post",
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

and here is the `route` part:

```
Route::post('percent/do', [PercentController::class, 'store'])->name('percent.do');
```

I would like it to bring me the result in `console.log(data)` like this:

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  ...
```

but it executes all the `for` to later bring me the result and that's not what I want

Comment: You can instead return all results and then use setTimeout() on the frontend to display them one by one.

Comment: Another way would be to use setInterval or chained requests using javascript promises to call each request one by one.

Comment: but what if I'm using multiple files in the form checking in php if there are duplicate files, already to work I will have to remove this validation

Comment: What do you mean by multiple files in the form? You can make several multiple requests using AJAX one by one